# Shiny - reset the value of the input when it is hidden?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I reset the value of an input when it is hidden? Or better - don't send the data to the server when it is hidden. Is it possible?

For instance:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Click the button"),
  sidebarPanel(

    radioButtons(
        inputId = "switch",
        label = "Select hide or show:",
        choices = c(
            "Show" = "show",
            "Hide" = "hide"
        ),
        selected = NULL,
        inline = FALSE
    ),

    conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.switch == 'show'",
        numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 0)
    ),

    actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text")
  )
))


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # builds a reactive expression that only invalidates
  # when the value of input$goButton becomes out of date
  # (i.e., when the button is pressed)
  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$n
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
})
```

The UI still sends the data of this numericInput to the server when 'Hide' is checked and the numericInput is hidden. I don't want the UI sends the data when the input is hidden. Or - reset it to 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how shiny and reactivity works. The UI isn't sending any values when the input is hidden. The value of the input is only sent at the time that you change it. Afterwards, whether it's hidden or shown, the value just exists already. You can't simply "delete" an input value from the server. If you want, you can hide the output on demand. Another thing you can do is "reset" it to 0 on demand - look into the `updateNumericInput()` function or at `shinyjs::reset()`. But the basic idea that shiny is sending the value when it's hidden is false

Comment: @DeanAttali got it working as I want now with `updateNumericInput()` thanks.